# Is there a light cured resin (UV or another) that I could make in my house with easy to find chemicals?

Tags: photochemistry

Is there a light cured resin that I could make in my house with easy to find chemicals? It does not matter if the finished product have practical or commercial applications as long that is not too toxic.

I want to use it for SLA 3D printing of prototypes.

Comment: Unlikely. Perhaps you can be a bit more specific about what you want to use it for.

Comment: I want to use it for SLA 3D printing of prototypes

Comment: I don't know what that is. Please elaborate.

Comment: Here is a good explanation https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fUxz_1UfdaM and here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yW4EbCWaJHE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are simple light-curing chemicals, such as the [gelatin-dichromate system](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6222838/), that you could make at home. However, the specifications for stereolithography are rather rigid, and it is doubtful that you could synthesize a monomer that doesn't corrode the system, that has the correct viscosity, has long-term stability and is not toxic.

You might do better taking up [gum dichromate photography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gum_bichromate), which is 2D printing.